How to convert NASA GPM data from HDF5 to GeoTIFF using python or gdal?
I'm trying to convert an HDF5 file to GeoTIFF, but I am having trouble. It's specifically an HDF5 file from this source, I have had success using gdal_translate on other HDF5 files. An example file can be found here from NASA's ArthurHou Server (you might need to make a free account with NASA to download the data) or also here from a google drive. It's a pretty standard HDF5 file. It opens fine with Panoply but trying to convert to GeoTIFF or opening in QGIS is weird. It should look like a satellite swath but it looks like this

Here is my sample code using python and gdalwarp. I grab the GCPs to get the extent then use the extent in a gdalwarp command. I've also tried rasterio and am having no luck. I keep getting the same weird looking data. Any help would be appreciated.
subdataset_path = "//FS/CSF/flagShallowRain"

try:
    result = subprocess.run(
        ["gdalinfo", f"HDF5:{input_file}:{subdataset_path}"],
        capture_output=True,
        text=True,
        check=True,
    )
    output = result.stdout
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print("Error running gdalinfo:", e)
    print("Output:", e.output)
    exit(1)

gcps = []
gcp_pattern = r'\((\d+\.\d+),(\d+\.\d+)\) -> \(([\d\.-]+),([\d\.-]+),\d+\)'

matches = re.findall(gcp_pattern, output)

gcps = []
for match in matches:
    pixel, line, lon, lat = map(float, match)
    gcps.append({"pixel": pixel, "line": line, "lon": lon, "lat": lat})

xmin = min(item['lon'] for item in gcps)
xmax = max(item['lon'] for item in gcps)
ymin = min(item['lat'] for item in gcps)
ymax = max(item['lat'] for item in gcps)

gdal_warp = f'gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -te {xmin} {ymin} {xmax} {ymax} {input_filepath} {output_file}'



About your sample file.
On my side I get:
Unauthorized
This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

@Greg7000 it's through NASA you will have to make an account to access it, unless you know of a better way to put the sample file here? Maybe a google drive link?

For now, I can't. That being said I recommend you try https://pypi.org/project/PyExifTool/ which seems to have some support of GeoTIFF (https://exiftool.org/TagNames/GeoTiff.html) it might be able to accomplish what you want. If I find some free time I might try to find the solution.

@Greg7000 I don't think PyExifTool works with HDF5 at least I can't get it to. If you wanna give the hdf5 file a shot I uploaded it to google drive so you don't have to make an account https://drive.google.com/file/d/13sxCixoZ44_rmddxQybzOhRb7gdxRBoI/view?usp=share_link

Do you have the dataset name?

@Greg7000sorry, yes it's "//FS/CSF/flagShallowRain"

What does the file look like in Panoply?

What CRS does QGIS show in the bottom right of the status bar when you open the file there?

@Joooeey, A Panoply plot of the data shows a narrow satellite swath circling almost all the way around Earth. JWB indicates he is trying to plot the /FS/CSF/flagShallowRain variable in the file, which has dimensions nscan,nray. The lon and lat coordinates for each point in the data grid are provided by 2D auxiliary coordinate variables /FS/Longitude and /FS/Latitude which have those same dimensions.
